# Randomly Generating Combinations From Variable Weights

Tags: probability, algorithms

## The Question

I have a list *A* of *n* objects.  Each object *A<sub>n</sub>* has a variable percentage *P<sub>n</sub>*.

I want to create an algorithm that generates a new list *B* of *k* objects (*k* <  <sup>*n*</sup>/<sub>2</sub> and in most cases *k* is significantly < <sup>*n*</sup>/<sub>2</sub>.  *Ex. n=231 , k=21*).  List *B* can have NO duplicates and will be populated with objects originating from list *A* with the following restriction:

> The probability that an object *A<sub>n</sub>* appears in *B* is *P<sub>n</sub>*.

Is this possible?  If so, what is the logic behind it?

Comment: Can an object from $A$ appear more than once in list $B$?

Comment: @muaddib NO!  Thanks for asking I forgot this in the question

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with this setup.  I'll give two extreme examples of what could not be done and a comment on what I think is the general problem.

First say we generate a very large number of lists $B$.  Then I interpret the probability $P_j$ as being the approximate portion of lists we would find $A_j$ in.  If our algorithm is successful, the approximation becomes more exact as we generate more lists.

Scenario 1: All of the $P_j$ are probability 1.  Now any choice of $k < n$ can't satisfy this.  We would have to find all $n$ objects in every list, which is impossible.

Scenario 2: All of the $P_j$ are probability zero.  In this situation, no lists could contain any objects.

In general, say we generate $N$ lists and each $P_j$ is realized almost perfectly.  Then we would find an approximate total of $N(P_1 + \cdots + P_n)$ items in the lists.  However, each list also contains $k$ items so that is a total of $Nk$ items.  For this to work, we would at least need the following satisfied:
      $$P_1 + \cdots + P_n = k$$